# Load data from Kafka topic to RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, apache-kafka, amazon-rds

I have a huge amount of data coming from kafka topic. What is the best way to transform(some data is encripted and I don't need all the infos) and load part of that data into RDS database on AWS. I have tried doing it with lambdas but due to large amount of data it was not possible. I have been advices to do it trough JDBC sink connector, but i am not sure about all the steps. Any explenation would come in handy :)

Tried with lambdas but the amount of data just bloked the lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Connect cluster running. It's not super complicated, as it abstracts a lot of consumer/producer concepts and wraps it into a simple JSON configuration file which is all that you deploy.

First look into getting into the Connect ecosystem. Confluent offers a JDBC Sink connector.

The connector and its configuration properties is documented here: https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/jdbc/current/sink-connector/overview.html

Then you should take a look into SMTs (Single Message Transforms) that can be applied on connector level. This should let you easily transform data before writing to RDS, provided you have deployed Connect (there are possibilities to deploy on a single instance with minimal effort)

Comment: Aiven and IBM also have a jdbc kafka connector. It's not part of Confluent Platform

Comment: You're right, I always thought Connect is an additional service made by Confluent but it is indeed part of the open source project.